# background dont work in chart.js

Tags: angularjs, charts, angular-chart

I would like to ask for help with the following, the code works fine, but what does not work is the background of the bars of the graphics, that would be basically thanks

```
$scope.labels = ['JAN', 'FEB', 'MAR', 'APR', 'MAY', 'JUN', 'JUL', 'AUG', 'SEP', 'OCT', 'NOV', 'DEC'],

$scope.type = 'StackedBar';
$scope.series = ['2015', '2016'];
$scope.borderWidth=0;

$scope.data = [
    [19, 38, 29, 34, 26, 49, 11, 46, 3, 36, 12, 24],    
    [52, 59, 65, 30, 27, 27, 77, 33, 63, 44, 45, 45],
    [29, 3, 6, 36, 47, 24, 12, 21, 34, 20, 43, 31],
];
$scope.datasetOverride=[{yAxisID:'y-axis-1'},{ yAxisID: 'y-axis-2' }, {
    borderWidth:1,
    type:'line',
    borderColor: 'rgba(34,34,34,0.3)',
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(34,34,34,0.2)',
},
{  
    borderWidth:0,
    type:'bar',
    backgroundColor: '#000000',
    borderWidth:'5px'                
},
{
    backgroundColor: '#000000',                
    borderWidth:0,
    type:'bar',

}];
$scope.options = {
  scales: {
    xAxes: [{
      stacked: true,
    }],
    yAxes: [ 
        {
            stacked: true,
            display: false,
         },
        {
            id: 'y-axis-1',
            type:'linear',
             position: 'left',
              backgroundColor: '#000000',  
        },
        {
            id: 'y-axis-2',
            type:'linear',
            position: 'right',
             backgroundColor: '#000000',  
        },
    ]
  }
};
```

here de codepen: http://codepen.io/fernandooj/pen/LRYxJJ?editors=1010

Answer (score 0):

You can change apply the background color on the HTML .panel-body class:

```
<div class="panel-body" style="background-color:#000">
```

It would be better if you create a CSS style to apply the background-color and other stylingproperties

Comment: I ask wrong, it was the bottom of the bars of the graphics does not work